# How to start postgreSQL9.4 server installed by homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I install postgresql9.4.5 by homebrew.
Before 9.4.5, I used 9.3.9 by macport, but I want to use only homebrew.
So I uninstall 9.3.9 and macport and install 9.4.5 by homebrew.

I could success "initdb /usr/local/var/postgres".
But, when I enter "postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres", show error.

```
The error
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

I tyied to start server by manual 
`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

But, `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status` show `pg_ctl: no server running`.

I confirmed pg_hba.conf and it shows

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Also, when I enter `psql`, shows the error `psql: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory`

What do I need to do? Please tell me.

Add a postscript
I also tried `ps aux | grep postgres`

```
postgres          276   0.0  0.0  2470236    452   ??  Ss   火12AM   0:03.18 postgres: stats collector process     
postgres          275   0.0  0.0  2614684   1160   ??  Ss   火12AM   0:11.63 postgres: autovacuum launcher process     
postgres          274   0.0  0.0  2614552    416   ??  Ss   火12AM   0:00.79 postgres: wal writer process     
postgres          273   0.0  0.0  2614552    440   ??  Ss   火12AM   0:00.81 postgres: writer process     
postgres          272   0.0  0.0  2614552    596   ??  Ss   火12AM   0:00.07 postgres: checkpointer process     
postgres          242   0.0  0.0  2614552   1184   ??  S    火12AM   0:01.07 /opt/local/lib/postgresql93/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb
root               75   0.0  0.0  2469228    884   ??  Ss   火12AM   0:00.03 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=postgresql93-server --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql93-server/postgresql93-server.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql93-server/postgresql93-server.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql93-server/postgresql93-server.wrapper restart ; --pid=none
```

This shows some process is active. And, 2 lines show macport pass. But, I had deleted /opt/local folder.
I killed these process and `ps aux | grep postgres` did not show anything.
So, I tried `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`. Next time, this shows

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-11-19 18:45:38 JST
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

And, the terminal stopped and did not show prompt. So I had to enter 'control + c'

But, I could start postgres manually. I did this command `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`
And I could do `psql` commands.

Comment: Why not run postgres.app? So much easier.

Comment: I want to use some softs extending the postgresql function at homebrew. I think they have dependencies. So I want to use homebrew only.

Comment: Is it possible that you still have an old version of postgres running on that port?  Try `ps ax | grep postgres`

Comment: I added a postscript.